# Why does picture-in-picture show invisible content?

Tags: android, android-picture-in-picture

I have something very strange:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayoutRoot"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fooFragment"
                android:name="net.mydomain.android.FooFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigationView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            app:itemBackground="@drawable/layout_background"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_single_view" />

    </DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```

Please note android:visibility="invisible" of FrameLayout.  The normal screen is exactly as expected - nothing shows:

[image]

However, picture-in-picture shows the following:

[image]

It shows the content (the fragment) outside of FrameLayout that is supposed to be invisible.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

The picture-in-picture is done by following [the official guideline](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture).  Nothing special.

**[Edit] 2019-08-26:**

I added

```
android:layout_margin="10dp"
```

to the invisible FrameLayout.  The result is exactly the same. This means the gray box is the root layout.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using this layout, versus one for some other screen size, when in PiP mode? If you are sure that this is the correct layout... does Android Studio's Layout Inspector work for a PiP activity? If so, that may give you some clues. I can't determine, from just the screenshot, which element from your layout is the gray box and which element from your layout is the photo (or whatever that is around the gray box).

Comment: There is only one layout for this activity.  To help clarify this, I added android:layout_margin="10dp" to the invisible FrameLayout.  The result is exactly the same.  The image is the content of fragment. I believe the graybox is the entire layout or DrawerLayout.  I changed its background to aqua, now the entire screen of the normal view and the box in pip becomes aqua. The layout inspector shows nothing but aqua color no matter which element I select.